# Xarmaim Bind to list of buttons

Tags: xamarin, button, bind

The following code works.  But, I do not want to bind a ListView Name="Choices" I want to bind to buttons.

The Choices are a String list.

So I think I need to somehow change:

```
<ListView x:Name="Choices"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}"
  RowHeight="20">
</ListView>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="FCMD.Views.ItemsPage"
         Title="{Binding Title}"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FCMD.ViewModels"  
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:FCMD.Models"  
         x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Question">
                    <Label Text="{Binding QuestionCapitalCity}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                        FontSize="16" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Instruction}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="13" />
                    <ListView x:Name="Choices"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}"
                            RowHeight="20">
                    </ListView>                        
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

Comment: add a template to your inner StackLayout that will generate a `Button` for each item in `Choices`

Comment: I meant inner **LIstView**

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `BindableLayout` to display a collection of items without wrapping it in another `ListView`.

You can refer to the following code snippet:

```
    <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Type}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>

                        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Inner_Items}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                        <Label Text="{Binding layer_name}"/>

                                        <Button  Text="{Binding layer_name}" />
                                      

                                    </StackLayout>
                                    
                                    
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```